# how to delete folder inside a folder using laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, directory

Im new in laravel ..1st im create some folders. and display all the folders..then Im trying to delete folder. when im select a folder and I want click delete button that selected folder deleted from main folder and database. my controller.php code is here

```
public function deletealbum($id)
    { 
      $albums= ForumAlbum::find($id);
    File::deleteDirectory('/img/Albums/', true);//delete image from temporary folder img/gallery  
      if (!is_null($albums))
      {
        $albums->delete(); //delete image from database
        return Redirect::route('viewalbum')
        ->with('success',' Delete Album successfully');
      }}
```

its working...but the problem is the folder name deleted only from database .not  in main folder.how to delete folder inside a folder using laravel 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the path you pass in. You should really use one of Laravels generators to get a full path to your folder. Assuming `img` is a directory in `public` you can do this:

```
File::deleteDirectory(public_path('img/Albums/' . $albums->albumname));
```

Assuming the name of the subdirectory is stored in `$albums->albumname`

Comment: its code is working..but (public_path('img/Albums/') complete deleted ..I want not like this..public/img/Albums/ contain another folders inside the Album folder(eg:img/Album/gallery,img/Album/image,img/Album/home,...)when im select gallery and click delete button its only delete gallery folders..(not all img/Album folder)

Comment: And the album name is stored in the `ForumAlbum` model?

Comment: yes. its save into database(table: albums) and field name :albumname

Comment: Then just add it to the path. See the updated answer

Comment: this code im already tryed...but only delete the image fom that folder .not folder delete... im using this code public function deletealbum($id)
{ 
  $albums= ForumAlbum::find($id);
  File::deleteDirectory(public_path('img/Albums/' . $albums->albumname), true);
 
  if (!is_null($albums)) 
   {
     $albums->delete();//delete Album from database
     return Redirect::route('viewalbum')
    ->with('success',' Delete Album successfully');
   }
} but web page not seen the deleted folder...

Comment: Do `dd(public_path('img/Albums/' . $albums->albumname))` and check if the path is correct

Comment: im check the path using  this code dd(public_path('img/Albums/' . $albums->albumname));. Im select folder is xcv got the answer is string(40) "C:\xampp\htdocs\sb\public/img/Albums/xcv" .

Comment: Well you passed `true` as second argument. That means the directory itself won't be and it will only be emptied. Just omit that second parameter and it should work fine.

Comment: thank you this work..one more doubt...when im delete folder also delete database(Album) im upload images are insert  into galleries table and save folders ,,,when im delete folder that images are also deleted ..how to delete that images from galleries table (im passing folder id from Albums table)galleries table contain galname,galimg,album_id..

Comment: The simplest would be to let the database do the work by setting the foreign key constraint to **on delete: cascade**

Comment: This has nothing to do with Laravel and I'm sure you'll find out how to do this on your own. You aren't the first having this question...

Comment: It's not very difficult. Just click the checkmark next to the question. [Click to view a guide on how it works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

$data = FileUpload::FindOrFail($id);
        $fnm = $data['path'];

```
    File::delete('upload/'.$fnm);

    $data->delete();
```